# How do I see all errors for JSON Schema's OneOf using .net JSchema

Tags: c#, json, json.net, jsonschema

I've created a small test with two classes from which I use the JSchemaGenerator to create a JSON Schema (using Json.NET). The schema seems to be generated correctly but when I test it against input containing errors, the output is not what I'd expect.

The errors that should be detected are:

- A missing property
- Invalid enumeration value.

Instead the only one error is found due to a missing property but reported in a very generic way and the invalid enumeration values seems to be ignored entirely.

What am I missing ?

The classes are defined as:

```
public interface IExample
{
    int ID { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}

class ExampleObj : IExample
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public enum EnumExample
{
    Value1,
    Value2,
    Value3,
}

class Derived1 : ExampleObj
{
    public EnumExample EnumValue { get; set; }
}
```

And the schema is generated using:

```
JSchema exampleSchema = generator.Generate(typeof(ExampleObj));
JSchema derivedSchema = generator.Generate(typeof(Derived1));

JSchema schemaCollection = new JSchema
{
Type = JSchemaType.Array,
Items = {
    new JSchema
    {
         OneOf = { exampleSchema, derivedSchema }
    }
},
ExtensionData =
{
        ["references"] = new JObject
        {
               ["example"] = exampleSchema,
               ["derived"] = derivedSchema
            }
        }
};
```

The faulty input is:

```
string test = @"[
         {
            '$id': 'ExampleObj',
            'ID': 0,
         },
         {
             '$id': 'Derived1',
             'ID': 1,
             'Name': 'bar',
             'EnumValue': 'ValueX'
         }
    ]";
```

Comment: Where is your code which calls the validate function? The documentation says you can get more detailed information, but I can't help if I can't see the validation code.

Comment: What validation code are you referring to, something to the effect of :  
  
    `var jArray = JArray.Parse(test);
    IList<string> messages;
   
   jObj.IsValid(schemaCollection, ouit messages);`  

Is that what you mean ? 

The messages are quite detailed when validating the individual objects but wrong when testing against an array this way.

Comment: Indeed that was what I was asking. OK, in which case your question title is wrong, as you're not asking for more detail, but saying the validation is not working correctly.

Comment: I order for people to help debug your issue, you should include the actual code you are running. Consider adding the actual code which can demonstrate the issue, and consider also making a "fiddle" https://dotnetfiddle.net

Comment: Thanks, if I were asking people to debug my issue I'd certainly do that. However I'm asking if this approach is in line with what is expected to get all errors given the provided setup, if not what the right approach should be.

Comment: You are asking people to debug your issue though. If you can't GET the second error back, how do you know it's happening at all? To answer your question, I need to first see the JSON Schema that's being generated, and make sure you're schema is actually causing two errors given the instance in the first place.

Comment: Please see this SO guide on how to ask code related questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve